# Mucked hand. who wins?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I was playing heads up in a Texas holdem game and I mucked my hand. and the other player didn't realize and mucked also. Who gets the pot?

Comment: Could you provide details such as was there action, did someone bet, or was it just checked down. Your answer might be at this post: http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/what-happens-if-the-last-two-live-players-fold-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 6):

In this case it would be the player that mucked *last* that wins the hand. Just because the other player didn't know you mucked or didn't show his hand doesn't disqualify him from winning - he wins if he mucked last.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica there is no "turns" to mucking. You can choose to muck your hand any time you want. You can even make a bet and then immediately muck if you wanted to! In the action that is described by the OP you would say that the person to muck last one because his hand was the only live hand (all others mucked) and he won without showing his hand and just mucked.

Answer (score 3):

If your opponent did not release his hand then there would be no confusion, which is why it's smart not to release your hand until you've received the pot. However, the fact that there *is* confusion doesn't mean we can't sort it out. The pot is always awarded to the last live hand; at the moment you folded your opponent held the last live hand and so they are considered the winner.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rules, the game stops as soon as the is a clear winner/ winners (split pot), further actions do not count. This is like in (english) football, if a goal is scored and the ball bounces back out, and another player kicks it in the net again, it's still only 1 goal.